# Specification of output datatype

Tags: excel, vba

For instance, I wanted to declare the output of my function 'Maxwell' as Double would this be correct:

```
Function Maxwell (x,y) As Double 
    Maxwell = x + y 
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, but you should declare `x` and `y` too, otherwise they are `Variant`: `Function Maxwell(x As Double, y As Double) As Double`

Comment: What if I want them as integers and only the output as double ?

Comment: You can declare them as `Integer` but I recommend to use `Long` instead (`Long` is a bigger `Integer`). Note that if you add 2 `Integers` or `Longs` like `x + y` the result will also be `Long` but never a `Double`.